# UIButton width on ios 8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8

I have a stretchable background that i put on both my buttons and my text fields

I want the button to be the same width as the textfield, on ios 7, with the stretching i defined in the image assets it looks great
However in ios 8,all the buttons seem to display wider than the text fields

I am using the appearance protocol to set the background image

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_border"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[EABaseViewController class], nil] setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_border"]];
```

These are my slices
[image]

this is the original view in the storyboard, the green view is a button, and the yellow ones are text fields
[image]

This is how it looks like on ios 7 during runtime (which is good)

[image]

This is how it looks like in ios 8 during runtime (which is bad)

[image]

If i put the slicing to be like this :

[image]

instead of what is shown in the previous slicing picture, the width of the button is fine, and aligned with the text field, but then i lose the gradient border effect.

Is there a solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to my problem is to update my iphone from ios 8.0 to ios 8.1

sigh